# How to copy a particular entire row from excel using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

I'm having a problem in coding to select a particular entire rows from a excel sheet and paste it in a Web application page.

Comment: Please share your code which you have tried.

Comment: refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37027731/how-can-i-read-specific-rows-with-apache-poi/52942841#52942841

Answer (score 0):

You can read row by row using rowIterator, and select the particular row you want based on the condition.

Once you selected your desired row, use cellIterator as input values to Selenium commands for posting the values in webpage.

Sample read excel program using Apache POI:

```
package com.howtodoinjava.demo.poi;
//import statements
public class ReadExcelDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("howtodoinjava_demo.xlsx"));

            //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

            //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            //Iterate through each rows one by one
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            while (rowIterator.hasNext())
            {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                //For each row, iterate through all the columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                while (cellIterator.hasNext())
                {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    //Check the cell type and format accordingly
                    switch (cell.getCellType())
                    {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                            System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "t");
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "t");
                            break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
            file.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Source: http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/06/19/readingwriting-excel-files-in-java-poi-tutorial/